# DDD enforce aggregate invariants when a child entity changes state

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a `Contract` entity which has a `DateRange`(dateFrom, dateTo) property and a `Sales` collection.

Each `Sale` also has a `DateRange` property that must be inside the boundaries of `Contract`'s `DateRange`.

What is the proper way to enforce the above invariant when changing a `Sale`'s date?

```
public class Contract : Entity
{
    public DateRange Dates { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; private set; }
}

public class Sale : Entity
{
    public DateRange Dates { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeDates(DateRange dates)
    {
        Dates = dates;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The `Contract` dates can change anytime, so each `Sale` should be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Based on Your Current Requirements

Interpreting your requirements, `Contract` is the aggregate root, and `Sale` is an entity within the `Contract` aggregate.  As the requirement is that any Sale dates MUST lie within a set of Contract dates, any change to a sale date must be managed by the Contract, so it can first check the contract dates.

To do this, you would have a method on `Contract`, like:

```
public void ChangeSaleDate(long SaleId, DateRange dates)
{
    if (this.Dates.Surround(dates))
    {
        var sale = this.Sales.First(s => s.Id == SaleId);
        sale.ChangeDates(dates);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("New Sale dates must be between ...", "dates");
    }
}
```

This assumes you have a `SaleId` - or some other way of identifying a sale within a contract, and that you've implemented a `Surround` method on `DateRange` to support this kind of check.

Depending on your project structure, you could also mark the `ChangeDates` method on `Sale` as `internal` to ensure you don't accidentally call it from your application services.

From your comment, it's true, this mechanism can lead to a large number of methods on the aggregate root (`Contract`) as it enforces the invariants that apply to 'all' sales in the contract.  As a result, situations like this can be prompts to challenge the requirements...

### Challenging the Requirements

DDD lends itself to 'eventual consistency' between aggregates - as aggregates define a consistency boundary, if you want to define a rule that crosses the boundary, you have to accept that the rule may not *always* apply.

An alternative implementation would be to make the `Sale` its own aggregate.  In this case, you would not have an `ICollection<Sale>` property on the `Contract` - rather you'd just have a `ContractId` property on the `Sale`, and each sale would get its own globally unique identifier.

However, the viability of this technique depends on if Contract dates are allowed to change, and what should happen when they do... to illustrate:

To change the dates on a sale, you'd use the `ContractRepository` to get a `Contract`, and the `SaleRepository` to get a `Sale`, and possibly pass the contract to the date change method on the `Sale`:

```
public void ChangeDate(Contract contract, DateRange dates)
{
    if (contract.Id != this.ContractId)
        throw new ArgumentException("wrong contract", "contract");

    if (!contract.AreSaleDatesValid(dates))
        throw new ArgumentException("wrong dates", "dates");

    this.Dates = dates;
}
```

The risk here, because your contract and sale are not transactionally consistent, depends on if the contract dates can change.

If not, then this approach is simple and workable, and ensures that you can access Sales directly.

However, if they can, then the risk is that the Contract dates may change *at the same time* you are changing the dates on the sale and thus your rule will be - temporarily - broken.

But, this is where domain events may assist.  If your `Sale.ChangeDate` method published an event `SaleDatesChanged` and you handle the event asynchronously in a new transaction, then the handler could check if the Sale dates are still valid for the contract.

What happens next depends on your business requirements - alerting for manual review, or automatically change the sale dates to fit within the new contract dates?

Similarly, the `Contract.ChangeDate` method would publish `ContractDatesChanged` and the handler for this would check that all sales are within the contract dates and again, alert or adjust.

This is 'eventual consistency' from a DDD requirement - your rule that all sales must be within the contract dates will be met... eventually.

And this is why I said 'challenging' the requirements - if it would really be better to *allow* sales dates to go outside a contract date in these cases and to handle it in a business appropriate way, then you have challenged your requirements and developed a deeper insight into the domain.

Comment: I also have thought of this solution, but then the contract entity will have many functions like the above. Is this correct in terms of ddd? And even with the internal modifier, it doesn't stop other developers from using the method directly.

I have also read suggestions with Domain Events but i haven't found a complete impelementation.

Comment: Also what about testing? internal does not help.

Comment: Expanded my answer to illustrate how domain events can help - if you relax the requirements - and why you have to go via the Contract object if you really have a 'must always be true' requirement.

Comment: You can leverage `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attribute to permit visibility to test projects.  However, even better, as the business rule is contained in the `Contract` class, you'd test it via the Contract class.  It's easier not to mock domain entities when testing - rather, focus on testing the whole Aggregate (which includes `Contract` and `Sale`) and thus use the Contract method and then Assert the Sale state.

Comment: The Contract dates indeed could change at any time, so the Sales should be changed so that the Contract aggregate is consistent.

Comment: What does it mean to the business to change a sales date?  Is a sale a record of something that has already happened? If so, should you allow its date to change?  If it's a statement of intent of something that is going to happen, do you also have a State to indicate once the Sale has occurred so you can work out if it is changeable or locked?  Digging into these questions will help determine if an eventually consistent approach (with two separate aggregates) is viable, or if you truly need to keep Sale within the Contract aggregate.

Comment: I have simplified these entities for the sake of the example. But let's just say that the Sale's dates can change anytime for other procedures to use. Think of it like a price catalog where some things apply for the specified date range, but it can change anytime.

Comment: I will accept your "Based on Your Current Requirements" answer since this is the approach i will follow. thnx